# How to create page section based on JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have jQuery slider code that I want to populate via a JSON url. Below is a sample JSON I am starting with:

```
{
  "Context": null,
  "IsGeneric": false,
  "Items": [
    {
      "Description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla tincidunt condimentum lacus. Pellentesque ut diam....<a href="#" >read more</a>",
      "MediaUrl": "\/images\/image1.jpg",
      "AlternativeText": "15+ Excellent High Speed Photographs",
      "Height": 1050,
      "ThumbnailUrl": "\/images\/image1-thb.jpg",
      "Width": 1680
    },
    {
      "Description": "Vestibulum leo quam, accumsan nec porttitor a, euismod ac tortor. Sed ipsum lorem, sagittis non egestas id, suscipit....<a href="#" >read more</a>",
      "MediaUrl": "\/images\/image2.jpg",
      "AlternativeText": "20 Beautiful Long Exposure Photographs",
      "Height": 1050,
      "ThumbnailUrl": "\/images\/image2-thb.jpg",
      "Width": 1680
    },
    {
      "Description": "Liquam erat volutpat. Proin id volutpat nisi. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur facilisis sollicitudin ornare....<a href="#" >read more</a>",
      "MediaUrl": "\/images\/image3.jpg",
      "AlternativeText": "35 Amazing Logo Designs",
      "Height": 1050,
      "ThumbnailUrl": "\/images\/image3-thb.jpg",
      "Width": 1680
    },
    {
      "Description": "Quisque sed orci ut lacus viverra interdum ornare sed est. Donec porta, erat eu pretium luctus, leo augue sodales....<a href="#" >read more</a>",
      "MediaUrl": "\/images\/image4.jpg",
      "AlternativeText": "Create a Vintage Photograph in Photoshop",
      "Height": 1050,
      "ThumbnailUrl": "\/images\/image4-thb.jpg",
      "Width": 1680
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I transform it to this?:

```
    <div id="featured" >
      <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
        <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected" id="nav-fragment-1"><a href="#fragment-1"><img src="images/image1-small.jpg" alt="" /><span>15+ Excellent High Speed Photographs</span></a></li>
        <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-2"><a href="#fragment-2"><img src="images/image2-small.jpg" alt="" /><span>20 Beautiful Long Exposure Photographs</span></a></li>
        <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-3"><a href="#fragment-3"><img src="images/image3-small.jpg" alt="" /><span>35 Amazing Logo Designs</span></a></li>
        <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-4"><a href="#fragment-4"><img src="images/image4-small.jpg" alt="" /><span>Create a Vintage Photograph in Photoshop</span></a></li>
      </ul>

    <!-- First Content -->
    <div id="fragment-1" class="ui-tabs-panel" style="">
        <img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="" />
         <div class="info" >
            <h2><a href="#" >15+ Excellent High Speed Photographs</a></h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla tincidunt condimentum lacus. Pellentesque ut diam....<a href="#" >read more</a></p>
         </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Second Content -->
    <div id="fragment-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide" style="">
        <img src="images/image2.jpg" alt="" />
         <div class="info" >
            <h2><a href="#" >20 Beautiful Long Exposure Photographs</a></h2>
            <p>Vestibulum leo quam, accumsan nec porttitor a, euismod ac tortor. Sed ipsum lorem, sagittis non egestas id, suscipit....<a href="#" >read more</a></p>
         </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Third Content -->
    <div id="fragment-3" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide" style="">
        <img src="images/image3.jpg" alt="" />
         <div class="info" >
            <h2><a href="#" >35 Amazing Logo Designs</a></h2>
            <p>liquam erat volutpat. Proin id volutpat nisi. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur facilisis sollicitudin ornare....<a href="#" >read more</a></p>
         </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Fourth Content -->
    <div id="fragment-4" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide" style="">
        <img src="images/image4.jpg" alt="" />
         <div class="info" >
            <h2><a href="#" >Create a Vintage Photograph in Photoshop</a></h2>
            <p>Quisque sed orci ut lacus viverra interdum ornare sed est. Donec porta, erat eu pretium luctus, leo augue sodales....<a href="#" >read more</a></p>
         </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Building HTML via Javascript is a serious pain, even if you "cheat" and just build a string then DOM-ify it via .innerHTML. If you have control of the webserver generating that HTML, why not insert some pre-generated HTML instead each result, as a new 'HTML' parameter or something?

Comment: I think with the right tools it is as easy as generating HTML on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave it a shot for the divs part. I wrote it on top of my head so it may contain typos etc., but can give you an idea

```
for (var i=0; i< jsonDesc.length; i++) {
  $("<div>").attr("id", "fragment-"+(i+1))
      .addClass("ui-tabs-panel")
      .append$("<img>").attr("src", jsonDesc[i].Items.MediaUrl)
      .append(
          $("<div>").addClass("info").append(
              $("<h2>")
                  .append("<a>").attr("href", "#").html(jsonDesc[i].Items.AlternativeText)
            )
        );
  if (i>0) {
    $("#fragment-"+(i+1)).addClass ("ui-tabs-hide");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout jqote2 which depends on jQuery or underscore's _template method.

http://aefxx.com/jquery-plugins/jqote2/
http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/

your json example needs to have href escaped with \"

example using underscore

```
var x = _.template("hello world a is <%= a %>, <% for (var i=0; i < 4; i++) { %> <%= i %>     <% } %>", {a: 77});
```

x ; //# => hello world a is 77,  0  1  2  3

Answer (score 0):

Start with a dummy element in memory. This whole thing will be 100x faster if you build the HTML in memory and insert it into the DOM all in one go, rather than repeated DOM writes.

```
var myOutput = document.createElement('div')
```

Then you loop through your data and append content into "myOutput" until you're done.

```
$(myOutput).append(....)
```

See: `http://api.jquery.com/append/`

Then append it into the page:

```
$('body').append(myOutput)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552934/what-javascript-templating-engine-do-you-recommend) and its answers.

If it doesn’t work for you, try googling for "Javascript templates".

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at a client side templating mechanism e.g. [jQuery.tmpl](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl) or [Embedded JavaScript](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#&who=jQuery.EJS). The tab part of your example in EJS would look like this:

```
<% $.each(Items, function(index, item) { %>
    <div id="fragment-1" class="ui-tabs-panel" style="">
        <img src="<%= item.MediaUrl %>" alt="" />
         <div class="info" >
            <h2><a href="#" ><%= item.AlternativeText %></a></h2>
            <p><%= item.Description %></p>
         </div>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Plain JS:

```
<script>
var res = {
  "Context": null,
  "IsGeneric": false,
  "Items": [
    {
      "Description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla tincidunt condimentum lacus. Pellentesque ut diam....<a href="#" >read more</a>",
      "MediaUrl": "\/images\/image1.jpg",
      "AlternativeText": "15+ Excellent High Speed Photographs",
      "Height": 1050,
      "ThumbnailUrl": "\/images\/image1-thb.jpg",
      "Width": 1680
    },
.
.
.
  ]
}
window.onload=function() {
  var container = document.getElementById("featured");
  for (var i=0, n=res.Items.length;i<n;i++) {
    var item = res.Items[i]
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "fragment-"+(i+1);
    div.className="ui-tabs-panel"; 
    div.style="";
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src=item.MediaUrl;
    img.alt=item.AlternativeText
    var innerDiv = document.createElement("div");
    innerDiv.className="info";
    var header = document.createElement("h2");
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href="#";
    link.innerHTML=item.description;
    header.appendChild(link);
    innerDiv.appendChild(header);
    div.appendChild(img);
    div.appendChild(innerDiv);
    container.appendChild(div);
  }
}  
</script>
<div id="featured" >
      <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
        <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected" id="nav-fragment-1"><a href="#fragment-1"><img src="images/image1-small.jpg" alt="" /><span>15+ Excellent High Speed Photographs</span></a></li>
        <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-2"><a href="#fragment-2"><img src="images/image2-small.jpg" alt="" /><span>20 Beautiful Long Exposure Photographs</span></a></li>
        <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-3"><a href="#fragment-3"><img src="images/image3-small.jpg" alt="" /><span>35 Amazing Logo Designs</span></a></li>
        <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-4"><a href="#fragment-4"><img src="images/image4-small.jpg" alt="" /><span>Create a Vintage Photograph in Photoshop</span></a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With [DOMBuilder](https://github.com/insin/DOMBuilder/), you could do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/insin/kJVBS/1/

```
DIV({id: "featured"},
  UL({"class": "ui-tabs-nav"},
    LI.map({"class": "ui-tabs-nav-item"}, items, function(item, attrs, idx) {
      attrs["id"] = "nav-fragment-" + (idx + 1);
      if (idx === 0) {
        attrs["class"] += " ui-tabs-selected";
      }
      return A({href: "#fragment-" + (idx + 1)},
        IMG({src: item.ThumbnailUrl, alt: ""}),
        SPAN(item.AlternativeText)
      );
    })
  ),
  DOMBuilder.fragment.map(items, function(item, idx) {
    return DIV({id: "fragment-" + (idx + 1), "class": "ui-tabs-panel"},
      IMG({src: item.MediaUrl, alt: ""}),
      DIV({"class": "info"},
        H2(A({"href": "#"}, item.AlternativeText)),
        P({innerHTML: item.Description})
      )
    );
  })
)
```

You'll also be able to use this exact same code to build the corresponding HTML for insertion with `innerHTML` (including registration of any event handlers you define) if the DOM approach starts to become noticeably slow.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the new (still in beta) jQuery tmpl plugin from Microsoft. It's much more concise than manually building the DOM elements yourself.

A full implementation example for your question is here.

http://jsbin.com/afoko5/latest

This generates the html you want, but it doesn't look very good because of the missing images and css classes.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) is perfect for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle I created with your sample data:
http://jsfiddle.net/subhamsaha1004/ct3sw/

It has a basic templating feature included that makes it easier to create the html. It uses pure javascript. The code has been kept very simple as the purpose was only to create a demo which you can further build upon.

The parser code looks something like this:

```
var Parser = {
    template: '<div class="slide"><img src="{{imgsrc}}" alt="" /><div class="info" ><h2><a href="#" >{{title}}</a></h2><p>{{description}}</p></div></div>',
    compile: function(template, data) {
        template = template.replace(/\{\{imgsrc\}\}/g, data.MediaUrl).replace(/\{\{title\}\}/g, data.AlternativeText).replace(/\{\{description\}\}/g, data.Description);

        return template;
    },
    parse: function(response) {
        var tpl = '', i = 0, len = 0, html = '';
        for(i = 0, len = response.length; i < len; i++) {
            tpl = this.template;
            html += this.compile(tpl, response[i]);
        }

        return html;
    }
};
```

Check the fiddle for the entire code.